# How to set the zoom percentage for an electron js application

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron

[image]Hi I am having a problem with my application which I made on electron js:

- My problem is that I don't know how to adjust the zoom on my app made on electron js on Google just do ctrl + scroll I want to have the same thing. I want make like google on my app

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXqBp.png
  [image]

Comment: We can't help you if you don't provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I do not understand why there's an upvote here.

Comment: Sorry i'm new to the site you want a picture?